# Angular Route order not making any difference

Tags: angular

My Angular routing setup has a couple of route configured. But the event/:id interferes with event/register. I thought that the priority would handle that issue.

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
          { path: '', component: EventComponent },
        {
          path: 'event',
          component: EventComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'event/register',
          component: RegisterEventComponent
          // canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        }, 
        {
          path: 'event/:id',
          component: EventComponent
          // canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        }

      ])
    ]
```

It returns this error:

```
    GET http://localhost:4200/event/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

How can i make this work?

Comment: any more details of the error?

Comment: I'm not sure how the routes are causing grief, might need more details on the error..

Comment: It simply wont load the page. If I remove one either the second or third route, it works fine. So the interfere with each other because of the same pattern.